# I'm looking for a way to retrieve the number of views of a Wordpress publication using an SQL query that is not a Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, view, count

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the number of views of a Wordpress publication using an SQL query that is not a Wordpress page and therefore cannot (I think) use Wordpress commands as an example:

`echo (int) get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'post_views_count', true) . View(s)';`

Seen on this page :

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144340/how-to-display-post-view-count

So my question is, which table in the DB contains the number of views for a publication?

And if a plugin like WPStatistics is installed (which is the case), does it change the location where this information is stored?

I'm surprised I can't find anything like this on the internet.

Thanks for any help.

I've been searching since this morning, and I've found a site :

https://instance-factory.com/?p=1598

which gives SQL queries to achieve this result, but when I test them they return empty lines.

So I'm wondering if installing a plugin like WPStatistics doesn't change the location of this information in the DB.

Thanks